# How can I change the meta tags of the page?

Tags: php, ajax, meta-tags

I created a php page and its content is loaded using jquery.
Can I change the meta tags of the page based on the loaded content in order to show correct information when post the link in Facebook ?

I tried to change the meta tags using JavaScript, but because It is client side it makes no effect, always the ordinal meta tags of the page is being displayed in facebook

Comment: jquery is a Javascript library. So it wouldn't work.

Comment: title and description meta tags in addition to meta tags of Facebook open graph

Comment: use variables? whenever you request the page content using jquery. reassign those variables.

Comment: assigning variables using jquery will make changes on the client side only !

Comment: no, that's not what i meant. first how do you request the content?

Comment: by clicking the link, a jquery code requests php page that generates the content 

 
     $('.details').click(function() { 
   $("a").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active"); 
         var id = $(this).attr("id");
     $.ajax({  
                type: "GET",  
                url: "details.php",
    data:{pid:id},
                success: function(html){  
     $("#persons").html(html).fadeIn(1000);
     
                }  
            }); 
   
     return false;  
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robots do not execute active content (ajax requests). So it is not relevant how it can be done in javascript, because facebook (or other robots) only sees the page as it is generated by the server at first moment.